# Browser refresh on screen size

Tags: jquery, page-refresh

I have implemented this to force a screen reload if the screen size changes width. However, it is not working in Firefox. Working ok on Safari and Chrome.

```
jQuery(function($){
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function() {
    if(windowWidth != $(window).width()){
    location.reload();
    return;
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Gah! Why?! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Comment: I know @ceejayoz. It was taking an older site where they had a script that had a rotating banner that would freeze on screen resize and needed a fix for it instead of redoing all at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

trying using `history.go(0);`

instead of `location.reload()`

you could also try something like

```html
<a id="reload-page" style="display:none" href="javascript:history.go(0);"></a>
```

```js
$('#reload-page').click();
```

Comment: have you tried using console.log("something") to see that you're getting within the if statement?

Comment: according to the documentation you're supposed to pass true into reload `document.location.reload(true);` though I doubt that's the problem here

Answer (score 0):

The browser is most likely trying to prevent a possible infinite loop.  Wrapping your reload in a timeout does the trick.

```
jQuery(function($){
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

  $(window).resize(function() {
      if(windowWidth != $(window).width()){
        setTimeout(function() {
          location.reload();
          return;
        }, 1);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: This technique may cause several (if not dozens/hundreds) of reloads during a slow resize of the window. I did `$(window).resize(function() { console.log('test'); });` on this question's window and got 44 resize events as I resized it. You really want to denial-of-service yourself into oblivion? OK.

Comment: I pointed out pretty much what you said, the browser doesn't want you to do this.  I just provided a workaround. Didn't say it was a good idea :)